# Как сделать динамические по высоте модальные окна?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот [тут](http://autopotok-service.hol.es/) я верстаю один шаблон, после того, как зайдете, нажмите на красный маркер на карте. Появится окно. В подвале есть кнопки, которые вызывают похожие окна. Так вот по ним весь вопрос. Хочу сделать в них фиксированные шапку и подвал. Путем изменения высоты контента окна и когда окно по высоте будет не убираться в монитор, то внутри появится полоса прокрутки, сделал ее при помощи **jquery.mCustomScrollbar**.

В файлике main.js есть код, которым я реализую данную задумку, он выглядит так:

```
var dynamicDialogSize = function(){
    var dialog = $('.dialog.dynamicDialogSize');

    dialog.each(function() {
        var el = $(this),
            heightFull = el.height(),
            dialogHeader = el.find('.dialogHeader'),
            dialogContent = el.find('.dialogContent'),
            dialogFooter = el.find('.dialogFooter');

        dialogContent.innerHeight(heightFull - dialogHeader.innerHeight() - dialogFooter.innerHeight());
    });
};
$('.dynamicDialogSize').on('show.bs.modal', dynamicDialogSize);
$(window).on('resize', dynamicDialogSize);
```

Почему-то, все окна при открытии занимают высоту больше чем она должна быть, внутри появляется пустое место, а если высоту браузера уменьшить, то подвал окна вылазит за его границы и если изменить размер окна браузера на пиксель, то все становится ок.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: по вашей ссылке 404 ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Может вам стоит вовсе обойтись без Javascript? Я так понимаю у вас проблема из-за необходимости пересчета отрицательных отступов у элементов при использовании трюка с `left: 50%; right: 50%;` и отрицательные отступы равные половине высоты/ширины блока.

В целом, вы можете указать для модального окна CSS стиль `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` и оставить трюки с отступами в прошлом веке ) а также головной болью с позиционированием. А реализацию полосы прокрутки также можно достичь через `overflow: auto;`